# Recognizer allocate Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, voice, speech-to-text, jsapi

I am trying to convert Speech to Text and im having no luck, I imported the JSAPI jar into my project but when I run my Script I get:

> ava.lang.NullPointerException
>       at CLAIRE.main(CLAIRE.java:13)

How do I change the variable from null and fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Recognizer rec = Central.createRecognizer(new EngineModeDesc(
                Locale.US));

        rec.allocate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSAPI implementation you're using does not support an US recognizer.
Check out `createRecognizer` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/javax/speech/Central.html#createRecognizer%28javax.speech.EngineModeDesc%29):

> **Returns:**
>          a recognizer matching the required properties or null if none is available